# How Can I Display Categories Description

Tags: categories

I need to Display Categories Description.

I create a new file category.php with archives.php template.

i try this function but its not working.

```
 <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`category_description( $category_id )` parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/#parameters) description:

> Category ID. Will use global category ID by default.

This means that if you are intending to use the global id, you don't need to insert the variable `$category_id` which may be undefined in your use of the function. I'm assuming it is undefined because it is not listed in the [global variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables). This is the default use of the function which will use the ID of 0:
`echo category_description();`

Otherwise, if you want the description of a specific category, pass the ID of that category as an argument, such as:

`echo category_description( 3 ); //gets the description for category with the ID of 3`